# How can I get all username from log entry table in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Sorry for the really noob question but I have django-auditlog working as expected but I am just having trouble pulling data out of Django-auditlog into my template.

Just wondering if there is an example project I can use to figure out where I'm going wrong?

`{% for data in auditlog %} {{data.actor_id}} - {{ data.name }} {% endfor %}`

actor id works but I can't get name to work

Comment: `data.actor.username` maybe?

Comment: @mousetail thank you for your response but its not working